# Installing .jad file on blackberry got error 907 invalid/missing cod file

Tags: android, blackberry, cordova

i build app for android and blackberry on build.phonegap.com and got.jad file for blackberry.
it is working on blackberry emulator fine. 
i installed .cod files on emulator by selecting all .cod files and importing them.

while downloading that jad file and installing on blackberry i got an error: 907 invalid COD

then i downloaded .cod files from bild.phonegap site and try to install them but got error: cannot open the file and shows symbol of ? on .cod file.

now i have .jad files and .cod files, please tell me how to install this app on blackberry.
thanks in advance.

My Emulator is not getting connected to internet how  can i connect it to internet.??

Comment: how r u installing file by using desktop manager or by web ?

Comment: i want to install app by OTA.

Comment: which is correct answer? i have install so many time with BBSAK my COD...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAD file is a metadata file that tells the device where to find the COD file. In the JAD there should be a line similar to:

```
RIM-COD-URL: MyApplication.cod
```

It is recommended that the URL be relative to the location of the JAD (as it is above). The system must be able to find and access the COD file(s) at the location specified.

Comment: i downloaded .jad file it contain similar line as uyou said above, also i downloaded COD files but no app is installed.

Comment: How are you "downloading" them? If you access a JAD with the BlackBerry browser it starts the OTA installation process and will install the COD if it can find it.

Comment: On build.phonegap we get JAD file for blackberry.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem. blackberry limits the size of cod file to 64 or 65 kb . If your cod file size is more than that then it divides it into chunks of 64 kb each.
The solution is to take the cod file extract it you will more than one cod file copy that all along with the jad file on ur phone it would work !

Comment: i got 39 COD files and i copied all of it in my memory card but no app installed. should i install it in phone memory.?

Comment: first remove all the cod file then extract the 1st cod file and copy all the cod file except the 1st one. remaining all should be copied along with the jad file it will surely ork .as it is working for me .

Comment: Yeah just extract the cod , rename it to application.cod.zip and then unzip if all other remaining cod files will be displayed and just copy jad,jar and other cod files it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried software BBSAK? http://bbsak.org/

There is the section

```
Modify CODs -> install JAD
```

and find your app to install on BlackBerry.

Comment: For this do we have to connect BB device to system?

Comment: Yes. You must insert device password and sw recognize your device and next you can install jad on it. Try and let me know.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know the Blackberry system very well but don't you have a jar file also? This file should contain the program (if it works like it used to be with Midlets on mobile phones that support java).

Comment: No, for BlackBerry installation you do not need the JAR file.